# How do i use Factor function in R?

Tags: r, character

I am new to R.
I want to convert a gender column of Man and Woman from characters that it was originally to factors with two levels 0 and 1. I am using

```
df$gender<-factor(df$gender, levels = c(0:1), labels = c("Man", "Woman"))
```

but all i get is `NA NA NA NA...` when running str.

Any ideas?

I tried `as.factor` which turned them in factor but without labels

Comment: It looks like you have reversed the levels and labels in your factor() function call. .. Try this ->    df$gender <- factor(df$gender, levels = c("Man", "Woman"), labels = c(0, 1))

Comment: @AnkitWasankar I don't see an obvious dupe for that, I suggest you answer, perhaps starting with `df <- data.frame(gender = c("Man", "Woman"))` as data.

Answer (score 0):

Stemming off of *"originally to factors with two levels 0 and 1"*, I think your data looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(gender = factor(0:1))
df
#   gender
# 1      0
# 2      1
```

To change the levels from `0,1` to `Man,Woman`, use `` `levels<-` ``:

```r
levels(df$gender) <- c("Man", "Woman")
df$gender
# [1] Man   Woman
# Levels: Man Woman
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for you answers. I made a mistake before the original levels R produced were 1 and 2.

Comment: Still I don't seem to be able to combine all the functions together.

Comment: Your question has no sample data, I made this up. Please provide sample data with `dput(head(df))` to help. As for this last comment ... "combine all the functions together", please help me to understand: one call to `levels(..) <- ..` doesn't seem so onerous.

Comment: How do I do that pretty please?

Comment: How do you do *what*?